# next-css causing infinite compiling

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-loader

I've attempted following the instructions given on [the projects GitHub](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css).

Following what it says I made my next.config.js file the following;

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
module.exports = withCSS();
```

I don't have any custom options for NextJS yet.

However in my `Header` Componen I have the following:

```
import Head from "next";

import "../../test/css/bootstrap.min.css"

const Header = () => (
<Head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
</Head>
);

export default Header;
```

Whenever I attempt to visit a page with `import Header from "../components/layout/header"` the output just sits at `[ wait ]  compiling ...` and never moves.

Nothing is generated in `.next/static/css` like the documentation says it should.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your import should be:

```
import Head from "next/head";
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tested this out. Still didn't fix the compiling issue :(